# Excel conditional value in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, trying to set the value of a column based on the value of another column. Only 2 values in column. If N, set it to N/A but if Y, set it to the value of a column in another sheet in the workbook, something like 
`=IF(U59,"N","N/A",='CRS v4.2x.0'!E$12)`. I tried `LOOKUP()` too. Neither works.

Comment: That would have been a bad suggestion pnut. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(U59="N","N/A",'CRS v4.2x.0'!E$12)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19592873)

Comment: Interesting.  No question was asked, but implicitly the poster wanted a formula that worked, which I kindly provided.  I could have adopted the standard SO approach of treating him with contempt I suppose

Comment: I tried this before I posted and I get the error "You've entered too many arguments for this function".